# Should I use heat resistant paint when whitewashing a brick fireplace?

Tags: paint, fireplace, brick

We are going to whitewash our brick fireplace, similar to this picture:
[image: whitwashed brick fireplace]

What kind of paint do we need to use to accomplish this? Does it need to be heat resistant?

Note we are just whitewashing the face of the brick (the inside of the fireplace will be painted with a black heat resistant paint).

Comment: Note this question is close, but my main question is, is heat resistant paint necessary; http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16219/what-type-of-paint-should-be-used-to-paint-a-brick-fireplace?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan to "whitewash" it, I would highly recommend using whitewash (lime-based paint), not normal paint, though it's hard enough to track down these days that you may need to [make your own.](https://www.gsa.gov/portal/content/112558) The face of the fireplace does not need to be particularly heat resistant (though the inside ends of the face bricks may get quite warm), but whitewash will be moreso than paint, and I think it works better with brick than most normal paints do. White painted brick looks ugly in short order.

As for black paint on the inside, good luck with that if you actually light a fire in there. That's asking a bit much, quite frankly. There are truly high-temperature refractory paints, but most of them are pretty-near white. Most (all?) black pigments burn off at high temperatures.

Comment: Flat black grill paint would probably work fine, no?

Comment: No. Direct flame exposure easily exceeds the temperature rating of both grill and exhaust paints (quick look at rustoleum grill paint - 1200F. Some exhaust paints claim 1500F) Looking at the pictured fireplace, the parts where it's sooted up don't get too hot - probably some of the sides that have not been sooted up are also cool enough. The bit behind the logs where the soot is burned off - paint will also burn off. Build a bigger fire - more paint burns off. https://www.doctorfire.com/flametmp.html suggest a typical wood flame temperature as 900C or 1650F